# How Can PHP Communicate with Java Based Software?

Tags: java, php

I want to use NLP software from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml. However, the software is written in java and I need to use it in a PHP script. Is there any way for PHP to directly communicate with java?

Comment: Create an API that allow the two to talk.

Comment: Does that system access a database? Maybe you could read and write to the system in PHP via that?

Comment: There are packages for a lot of scripting languages on that page, it shouldn't be difficult to look how they work and implement it in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

If I understood what you want, it should help

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to Thrift package created by Facebook: http://thrift.apache.org/